# Extract json in column and place in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

| id | outgoing |
| --- | --- |
| 1939 | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing","old.a945248027_14454878":"cancelled",,"old.a945248027_454878":"cancelled"} |
| 1000 | {"a945248027_154878":"processing","new.a945248027_878":"cancelled"} |

I want to extract the content of the outgoing column as such

| id | outgoing | status | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1939 | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing","a945248027_14454878":"cancelled","a945248027_454878":"cancelled"} | processing | 14454878 |
| 1939 | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing","a945248027_14454878":"cancelled","a945248027_454878":"cancelled"} | cancelled | 14454878 |
| 1939 | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing","a945248027_14454878":"cancelled",,"a945248027_454878":"cancelled"} | cancelled | 454878 |
| 1000 | {"a945248027_154878":"processing","a945248027_878":"cancelled"} | processing | 154878 |
| 1000 | {"a945248027_154878":"processing","a945248027_878":"confirmed"} | processing | 878 |

I have written the query

```
select CAST(substring(key from '_([^_]+)$') AS INTEGER) as amount,substring(outgoing::varchar from ':"([a-z]*)"' ) as Status from table1 cross join lateral json_object_keys(outgoing) as j(key);
```

The query repeats the first status for all the status column

Comment: you have json  so use json functions

Comment: `select id, outgoing, v as status, split_part(k, '_', 2) as amount from table1 cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(outgoing) as j(k, v)`

Comment: `select t1.*, t2.status, substring(t2.amount from '_([^_]+)$')::int4 as amount from table1 t1 
cross join jsonb_each_text(t1.outgoing) t2(amount, status)`